# line width too long

Tags: 14.04, less

I am using laravel and running

```
php artisan route:list
```

and when i press enter the output is a grid of columns representing the name of the route, the uri, the action, and other columns. But the text in the different columns ends up being too wide for my window.

I tried using

```
php artisan route:list | less -+S
```

which helped with all but the first column.

Any suggestions?

[image: picture1]

Comment: @DevRobot, by fixing the code output you made it look like how its supposed to look. It doesnt look like that ony my screen

Comment: So it looks exactly like it does now?

Comment: No, I deleted it all together because Im not sure how to make it look here exactly like it does.

Comment: take a screenshot - probably the best idea